Ubuntu wine permission locked and wine32 no installation candidate
this damn thing WILL NOT WORK
i’ve spent probably 8 hours trying to install it.. file can’t be accessed permission locked
can’t boot it and can’t install cause wine32 has no installation candidate
every problem i’ve had leads to
me an endless search of new problems, wtf do i do? i just wanna get steam running

You've provided no specifics (ie. command and exact output) but your title implies a user error to me. A quick scan and I do see wine32 | 9.0~repack-4build3 | noble/universe           | armhf, i386 so assuming you've got the universe repository enabled and have added the appropriate architecture (you give no details here at all) you shouldn't have a problem... Check your commands & exactly what you did, as you probably have made your error there.  If you want us to provide specific help, you need to tell us exactly what you did (all commands, and include output of the last command)

Yes. it can be tricky to get WINE working & I am sorry you are having trouble.
Firstly you need to install the wine32 stuff as follows: -
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine32:i386

As a starting point install playonlinux which is a graphical front end and makes installation much easier. However, even then I have always found program installations problematic.
If possibly it is generally a good idea to create a new PREFIX for each program you install. Certainly until you perfect an install.
When not using playonlinux I put the command lines into a bash script to help manage things. (Program.sh) and set it to run.
sudo apt-get install playonlinux

but check your system is up-to-date first.
Some examples of running a wine program without playonlinux: -
Configure
This will create a new prefix environment of the name in WINEFPREFIX
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 exec winecfg
WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine64 exec winecfg

Example program
Installing is similar to this only you run the install program (this is a trial program) rather than the target.
WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/EXX2_340 exec wine '/home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/EXX2_340/drive_c/Program Files/Exxx Txxxx Sxxxxxxx x/bin/win_x86/exxxxxxxxxx.exe' 

After you have installed you will probably have to configure it. This is when your problems really start.
The following shows what is available to install: -
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 exec winetricks list

The following is installing dotnet45 using winetricks playonlinux has its own methods for this: -
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 exec winetricks dotnet45

Good luck
